# Recomendations for a file-system based .NET media library

Tags: asp.net, media-player, gallery

Can anyone recommend a media library/player module for an ASP.NET website that reads from a simple file-system rather than having it's own media store?

A client of mine is running an old image-gallery I wrote. They can copy images onto the server filesystem, create their own folders, and it is all rendered nicely into the front-end as a hierarchical, searchable image-gallery.

But this is long in the tooth and they'd really like something that can handle video (mostly h264 mov & FLVs), and if possible show thumbnails for the movies.

They very much like being able to manage the media via the file system and would prefer not to have to use a separate admin page and/or database system.

Obviously this could be built manually, and something like FFMPEG could be used for creating previews, but surely something decent exists already.

Something that can easily CSS styled is a plus.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gallery Server](http://galleryserverpro.com/) can do this. It's an open source ASP.NET gallery that synchronizes to your directory of media files, then renders them in the browser as albums and media objects.

Technically, it still uses a database, but the default database is SQL CE, which is stored as an SDF file in the App_Data directory and is invisible to the user, requiring no installation, configuration or ongoing management.

You can add/remove media files using Windows Explorer, FTP, or whatever, then let the auto-sync feature automatically keep the gallery up to date. No need to use the admin UI.

[Disclaimer: I am the founder and lead developer.]